# Spark Dataframe: Calculate variance between groups

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With R's dplyr I would calculate variance between groups like so:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(total = sum(value)) %>% summarise(variance_between_groups = var(total))
```

Trying to perform the same action with Sparks DataFrame API:

```
df.groupBy(group).agg(sum(value).alias("total")).agg(var_samp(total).alias("variance_between_groups"))
```

I receive an error in the second `agg` saying that it can't find `total`. I am clearly misunderstanding something so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_samp()` takes a String-type column name, hence you need to provide a String as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("a", 1.0),
  ("a", 2.5),
  ("a", 1.5),
  ("b", 2.0),
  ("b", 1.6)
).toDF("group", "value")

df.groupBy("group").
  agg(sum("value").alias("total")).
  agg(var_samp("total").alias("variance_between_groups")).
  show
// +-----------------------+                                                       
// |variance_between_groups|
// +-----------------------+
// |     0.9799999999999999|
// +-----------------------+
```

It can also take a column (of Column type), e.g. `var_samp($"total")`.  See Spark's [API doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@var_samp(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) for more details.